# JUnit Test failing and not sure why

Tags: java, junit, drjava

I'm pretty new to writing code and I am not the best, but I don't understand why my code isn't passing one of the JUnit tests I have set up.

```
public class PA3Test {


public static void main(String[] args) { 
}

public static int countMajority(int count0, int count1, int count2) {
    int allVotes = (count0 + count1 + count2);
    int halfVotes = (allVotes / 2);
    int winner = 999;
    if (count0 >= halfVotes) {
        winner = 0;
    } else {
        winner = -1;
    }
    if (count1 >= halfVotes) {
        winner = 1;
    } else {
        winner = -1;
    }
    return winner;

}
```

The test looks like this:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PA3TestTest extends TestCase {

public static void testCountMajority() {
    assertEquals("0th param should win:", 0,
                 PA3Test.countMajority(100, 50, 40));
     assertEquals("1st param should win:", 1,
                 PA3Test.countMajority(50, 100, 40));
}
```

It is supposed to be returning 0 but it is returning -1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The test is failing because your function is supposed to be returning 0 but it is returning -1, and because the test is testing that your function returns 0, which it doesn't.

Comment: @immibis what is the value of repeating the question as a comment?

Comment: @HadenSchlemmer Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger to see where it's doing something unexpected?

Comment: I must sound stupid but why is the function returning -1?

Comment: Very carefully consider what happens after the line `winner = 0;` executes.  What is the next line to execute, and the one after that?

Comment: If you don't know how to use the debugger I cannot show you in the space available.  You'll have to read the documentation or get someone to sit with you and show you.

Comment: OK thanks, do I need to be more specific the first line that says winner = -1?

Comment: @JimGarrison The question appears to be "why does the test fail?". The test fails because it is checking the return value is something other than what it actually is.

Comment: @immibis I'm just confused as to why the return value is -1 and not 0

Answer (score 0):

In your first test,
allVotes=190
halfVotes=95
count0 = 100 > 95, winner = 0
count1 = 50 < 95, **winner = -1**

---

Try below and find out what you are doing wrong.

```
public static int countMajority(int count0, int count1, int count2) {
    int allVotes = (count0 + count1 + count2);
    int halfVotes = (allVotes / 2);
    int winner = -1;
    if (count0 >= halfVotes) {
        winner = 0;
    }
    else if (count1 >= halfVotes) {
        winner = 1;
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Comment: Darn, the OP was so close I was hoping he would be able to figure it out on his own based on my hints. Oh well...

Comment: OK I understand the problem now, but now I am getting an error that says "else without if". Still a bit confused

Comment: This is much simpler than what I was trying to do and makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are averaging it by 2 when you are having 3 counts.
But based on your problem statement this should do the trick.

```
public static int countMajority(int count0, int count1, int count2) {
    int allVotes = (count0 + count1 + count2);
    int halfVotes = (allVotes / 2);
    int winner = -1;
    if (count0 >= halfVotes) {
        winner = 0;
    }
    if (count1 >= halfVotes && count1  > count0) {
        winner = 1;
    }

    return winner;
}
```